# Accessing module variable in javascript module

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JavaScript module as follow:

```
var QCH = (function($jquery, undefined) {

      var QCH = { };
      var someDivId;

      QCH.Init = function(someDivId) {
              someDivId=someDivId;
      };
      return QCH;
}($));
```

The above code doesn’t work. someDivId has the same name as module variable and local init variable.
In C#, we can use this.someDivId to point to the module(class)  variable. Is there any way to point to module variable in JS?

I know that I can change the name module variable and use for example capital case for it to be distinguish from local one, but I am wondering if there is any better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You will have to rename one of them. You have shadowed the `someDivId` in the outer scope with one in the inner scope, and JavaScript provides no way (that I know of) to ignore one element of the scope chain when resolving identifiers.